# AWS Certificate Manager Certificate is not visible to AWS Beanstalk from Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS and need help to select the AWS Certificate Manager provisioned Certificate from Elastic Beanstalk Loadbalancer using **AWS Console**.

1. Deployed my Java application on Linux instance using Elastic
   Beanstalk and that worked fine with Http.
2. Provisioned a new wildcard certificate using AWS Certificate Manager.
3. Under Elastic Beanstalk Configuration - Network Tier - Load Balancing Settings gear Icon, I changed "Secure listener port" = 443 and "Protocol" =
   HTTPS.
4. But the "SSL Certificate ID" does not list the certificate to pick.

Please suggest what is that I am missing here.

I have read many suggestions to do by CLI but I am not an CLI expert and wanted to use the console feature for simplicity.

EDIT-1:
I can see the certificate under EC2 - Load Balancer - Listener TAB if I try to add HTTPS, but not under Beanstalk. I am not sure if I shall add this listener under EC2 or not, but I think I need to add SSL to Beanstalk as My application get deployed using Beanstalk into EC2.

Comment: AWS Certificate Manager certificates .can be accesses through CLI only not from console

Comment: @Prabhat can you confirm if you see Status Issued in the ACM manager console?  Can you also confirm if in the details you see an Identifier for that certificate?

Comment: @error2007s I think AWS has allowed to pick the certificate from console but that does not work. Please refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

Comment: @RodrigoM I can see the status of the certificate as "Issued" in the ACM manager console and I can see the "Identifier" as well in detail.

Answer (score 5):

This will happen if you created your SSL Certificate on a different Region to your Elastic Beanstalk instance. An easy gotcha!

Comment: I was just reminded of this. Good answer (that shouldn't have been downvoted to 0).

Answer (score 1):

To setup a SSL certificate for your Elastic Beanstalk environment, please see [Configuring Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment's Load Balancer to Terminate HTTPS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html)

There is a console setup step as you describe in step 3, so that looks good.  Also note you need to update the EB configuration as shown in the above document.

Comment: I have followed the link and tried to configure the EB but I can't see the certificate in the dropdown. I think I might have missed some point or else the console does not work. But I can see the certificate under EC2 - Load Balancer - Listener TAB if I try to add HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

From [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html):

> For Classic Load Balancer and Application Load Balancer, if the
> drop-down menu doesn't show any certificates, you should create or
> upload a certificate for your custom domain name in AWS Certificate
> Manager (ACM) (preferred). Alternatively, upload a certificate to IAM
> with the AWS CLI.

I guess AWS CLI with IAM must be used as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl-upload.html)